# Render queries with ajax in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I need help or guidance with the following problem. I using ajax to reload dynamically queries from  database each time  is change in a search form.

The purpose is to dynamically  load N quantity of register according to the params selected in the search form.

I have this code that allow me to made queries to the database and printed the results in the index.  The code is working by the way, and finally each iteration prints a "square" () for each registry in the result of the query.

Controller:

```
 def clientsjson

      @search  =  Client.search(params[:q])
      @clients = @search.result

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @clients }
      end
  end
```

Js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".searchupdate" ).change(function() {

    $.getJSON("/client/clientsjson?"+$('#client_search').serialize(), function (data) {

        var $ul = $('<div></div>');

         $ul.append(data.map(function(data) {
                var $ini= '<div class=\"panel-mate bgray-o\"><div class=\"row\">'

                var $inicio='<div class=\"col-xs-4\" align=\"center\">'
                var $titulo='<h3 style="height:45px; width:100% overflow:hidden"><a class="h1-small" href="/es/auctions/'+data['id']+'">'+data['name']+'</a></h3>'
                var $titulo2='<h5 class="cursive txt-gray-lig negrita font-serif">City, Country</h5>'
                var $titulo3='<h5 class="cursive txt-gray-lig negrita font-serif">Idioma:</h5>'
                var $titulo4='<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" title="View comments" class="open-modal-auction" href="#myModalc'+data['id']+'"><h5 class="txt-auto" style="margin-top: 10px">'
          var $titulo5='Rating:<img src="/assets/estrella-991be5754e32c5209a9b4c697cf93320.png" alt="Estrella" width="20" height="20" /><img src="/assets/estrella-991be5754e32c5209a9b4c697cf93320.png" alt="Estrella" width="20" height="20" /><img src="/assets/estrella-991be5754e32c5209a9b4c697cf93320.png" alt="Estrella" width="20" height="20" /></h5></a>'
                var  $fin='</div>'

              var $column2='<div class=\"col-xs-5\" align=\"center\"><br>'
              var $parte1 ='<h4 class="negrita cursive font-serif">'+data['date']+'</h4>'
              var $parte2 ='<h3 class="negrita cursive font-serif" style="margin-top: 2px">Maximum Price<span class="txt-mor ">'+data['maximum_price']+'</span></h3> <h5 class="cursive txt-gray-lig"> Duración: '+data['duration']+'</h5>'
              var $parte3 ='<br/><p style="margin-top:-12px"><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" title="Bid" style:"width:120px;" class="open-modal-auction btn btn-morado luz-btn-mor" href="#myModal'+data['id']+'">Puja Avanzada</a></p>'
              var $column2fin='</div>'

              var $column3='<div class="col-xs-3 div-general" align="center" style="padding:">'
              var $column1='<p style="margin-top: 20px"><img src="/assets/bid-c355299aa9a59c701f6768169153b0e6.jpg" alt="Bid" width="75" height="50" /><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" title="Bid"  class="open-modal-auction" href="#myModalbids'+data['id']+'" style="margin-left:5px">Pujas</a></p>'
              var $form='<div class="borde-color-mora" style="padding-top:5px; margin-top:20px"><form novalidate="novalidate" class="formtastic bid" id="new_bid" action="/es/bids" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="QkFLk2OiMkFyMx5eeYqsAWex8DVeSpAT2YOnr1sY3kOIXKjsx4F0GRHs7a6byMCReue0Y82EScIUWXSErRxnhA==" /><div class="hidden input optional form-group" id="bid_auction_id_input"><span class="form-label"><label for="bid_auction_id" class=" control-label">Auction</label></span><span class="form-wrapper"><input id="bid_auction_id" value="1" type="hidden" name="bid[auction_id]" /></span></div><p align="left" style="margin-left:5px">Pujar  <input class="borde-color-mora" style="width: 100px; text-align:right" type="text" value="0.0" name="bid[amount]" id="bid_amount" /></p>'
          var $form2='<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Bid Fast" class="btn btn-morado luz-btn-mor" id="button-bid" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:20px" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off" /></form></div>'
              var $column3fin='</div>'

                var $end= '</div></div>'




         return $($ini+$inicio+$titulo+$titulo2+$titulo3+$titulo4+$titulo5+$fin+$column2+$parte1+$parte2+$parte3+$column2fin+$column3+$column1+$form+$form2+$column3fin+$end)
         }));

         $('#clientList1').html('');
         $('#clientList1').empty().append($ul);



    });

  });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="clientList1"></div>
```

Well, as I said before,  the code work  almost perfectly. But I have  two main issues.

1-)The model client,  have several model parents like: country, city, languages, etc.    The json query only brings the IDs  but dont let me to get the name  for printing.   Something like: "client.country.name".  So how I can access to the parents models so I can print the names and not the IDs

2-) Something similar to the first issue but with the  child models,  something like: "client.comments".  Normally I would this <%= render client.comments  %>  but I can't do this from JSON, so the question here is how I can access the child model associated with each register in the query.

There is a better way to do this?

thank you in advance.

////Update

After of calling this localhost:3000/client/clientsjson.json?q=test   in my browser, this is the output:

```
[{"comments":[]},{"comments":[]}, {"comments":[]}]
```

Json Builder file:

```
json.array! @clients do |client|
  json.id
  json.name
  json.rate
  json.address
  json.date
  json.numbercomments

  json.comments client.comments, :subject, :comment,:created_at

  json.country do
    json.name
  end

  json.city do
    json.name
  end

  json.language do
    json.name
  end

end
```

And here is the route I made in route.rb to call the action.

```
get 'client/clientsjson' => "clients#clientsjson", :as => 'clientsjson', :format => :json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) which both allow you to easily include associated data in your json response.

In your case here, you would simply need to create a view file at:

```
app/views/clients/clientjson.json.jbuilder
```

Then your jbuilder would look something like:

```
json.array! @clients do |client|
  json.id client.id
  json.name client.name
  json.rate client.rate
  json.address client.address
  json.date client.date
  json.numbercomments client.numbercomments

  json.comments client.comments, :subject, :comment, :created_at

  json.country do
    json.name client.country.name
  end

  json.city do
    json.name client.city.name
  end

  json.language do
    json.name client.language.name
  end

end
```

Then change your controller action to:

```
def clientsjson
  @search  =  Client.search(params[:q])
  @clients = @search.result

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
  end
end
```

Which should give you all the associated json nodes you need.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I have been trying to apply your suggestion and now it seems that queries results are empty or the objects are created without the DB values.  any ideas?

Comment: First of all, are you getting the JSON output you need? I didn't test that jbuilder code, so it might not be right. Can you hit localhost:3000/client/clientsjson.json?q=test and post your output?

Comment: I update the post with the output of the JSON. It is obvius is no giving me the results I need.   

Is giving me this:   [{"comments":[]},{"comments":[]}, {"comments":[]}]

Comment: Could you edit your question with your  jbuilder (or Rabl?) template?

Comment: Its done, I added the jbuilder template to the question

Comment: Does the fact that you are calling at http://localhost:3000/auction/auctionsjson.json?q=test and not http://localhost:3000/client/clientsjson.json?q=test in your question, have anything to do with this?

Comment: sorry I made mistake.  But  that  not is the problem.  I need the functionality for auctions and clients  and I have same difficulties with both.   Each call brings the number of objects but each object is empty.

Comment: I have updated the JBuilder code in my Answers (still untested though!). I think your jbuilder structure is still not quite right. Can you please also check the contents of your \@clients collection, by doing raise @clients.inspect in the controller. I am not sure if they are getting loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, let me say  your answer save my life ( this week  x'D )    Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @RiveroFelipe. Did you get it working OK?? If so, please do vote up my answer and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using jbuilder or RABL for generating the json. That gives you control over how much or little you need to bring back, and can also generate nested arrays for dependent records, etc.

For some like this, I'd also be tempted to use something like Backbone.JS and handlebars for the javascript templateing. You don't have to, but will more cleanly separate the HTML from the Javascript, making future changes to HTML or JS easier. Any JS templating system is probably better and none, but I've been happy with Backbone and Handlebars.