# How to properly render a collection in rails using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I find a solution using JSON but is not enough for why I need. The solution with JSON is here:  [Render with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875565/render-queries-with-ajax-in-rails/33876051?noredirect=1#comment55562611_33876051).

I need to render a specific partial  for each object  from a collection using Ajax so I can show all the functionalities I made in the partial and use certain validations are no possible to do with JSON.   The purpose is to dynamically do queries to the DB and render the results of the queries with each change in my search form.

this is my function in the controller

```
def clientsjson

      @search  =  Client.search(params[:q])
      @clients = @search.result

 end
```

To render the partial I need  (_client.html.erb), normally, I only use this:

```
<%= render @clients %>
```

But know I need to render dynamically with Ajax.

The Ajax function I use to detect the change in the form is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $( ".searchupdate" ).change(function() {
               $.getJSON("/client/clientsjson?"+$('#client_search').serialize(), function (data) {

           //*Here I use JSON to create a text and print HTML and works*//
         $('#clientList1').html('');
         $('#clientList1').empty().append($ul);
     });  
    });
 });
```

The index where I print the results (only the columns):

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4" >
        <%= render "searchform" %>
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8" >
        <div id="Auctionlist1">
          <%= render @clients %>
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions??

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a controller with an action that responds to the request from the change of .searchupdate, and you should render a js view for it.

If it is a simple GET request, you could have a remote link, such as

```
link_to my_path, '', remote: true
```

you alter its path using jquery, and click on it with jquery. It sends an ajax request to rails, it is received by your controller (you need to specify a route for it).

You need to add `respond_to :js` in that controller.

Then, if the action is say "index", in your `index.js.erb` you can execute any javascript you need, including rendering a partial:

```
$('.my-element').html('<%= j(render partial: '_my_partial.html.erb', locals: { my_var: @my_var }) %>');
```

If you need to send other kind of requests, such as POST, you may create a form with hidden inputs, point it to a desired endpoint, set the correct method and set `remote: true`. The rest is the same, with the difference that in your `$(document).ready()` you submit the form instead of clicking the link.